# RandomAccessFile vs Scanner vs FileInputStream in Java

Tags: java

I know a little about it, was just curious to know more.

`FileInputStream` reads in raw bytes from a file, as opposed to the `CharacterStream`s `FileReader` which reads in streams of character.

`RandomAccessFile` supports both reading and writing, also provides a file pointer using which one can jump into any point in the file.

`Scanner` can be used to read in any input, even a file. It parses the input into tokens.

So which to use when?
Is `Scanner` limited to only text files and the other two can be used to read any file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Scanner and FileReader are limited to text.

FileInputStream and RandomAccessFile are limited to binary (or ASCII text files)